# AIR > browseForSave strange behaviour

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I just noticed something weird in my app.

I have a "save" button that triggers this function:

```
 var saveFile:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(nameOfProject+".uct");
 saveFile.browseForSave("Save as");
 saveFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, saveFileToSystem);
```

When clicked, it display the "browse for save" window with a suggested name file.
Now I've noticed that when exporting, installing and running the app, when I click the button for the first time everything it's ok, but when I clicked again the location looks like this:

[image]

The "where" field is the same file....? And even if I click save, it doesn't save. The strange stuff is that this is not happening while testing my app in Flash Builder.
Any hint?

Comment: This is a bug, and it's new with newer versions of Air, as far as I can tell -- not sure exactly where it changed, but it happens with Air  3.4.0.2540. Older versions would, correctly, show the "Where" as the directory.

Comment: Further checking: it works as expected in Air 3.2.0.2070, but is broken in 3.3.0.3670 / 3.4.0.2540 / 3.4.0.2710.

Comment: I just bugged this; it's 3345174 in bugbase. This only happens if the output file already exists (ie, the second time around) -- so a potential workaround would be to rename the output file to something else temporarily while the 'save' happens, then either rename it back if the user cancels, or delete the old renamed one if the user saves a new version of the file. This seems a bit risky to me, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the workaround above, and it seems to do the trick. Code is something like this:

```
var saveFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("output.file");
var tempMovedAway:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("temp.temp");
currentFileRenamedForAirBug = picker.clone();
currentFileRenamedForAirBug.moveTo(tempMovedAway), true);
saveFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function():void {
        tempMovedAway.deleteFile();
    } );
saveFile.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, function():void {
        tempMovedAway.moveTo(currentFileRenamedForAirBug);
    });
saveFile.browseForSave("save file"); 
// MUST be sure to call saveFile.browseForSave, or you risk losing an existing file.
```

You can wrap this lot in checks for the Air runtime (NativeApplication.nativeApplication.runtimeVersion) and Mac-only, to avoid doing this any more than necessary.

Also, if your file save code could rely on making changes to an existing file (rather than creating an entirely new one), you'll need to tweak this a bit.